# Can't understand this Recursive Function

Tags: c++, function, recursion

How is this giving the output from 1 to 10? Shouldn't the output be 0 ?
While debugging i can see that the cout is called serveral times at the end but where is the addition being performed at ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void func(int n);
int main()
{
    func(10);
    return 0;
}

void func(int n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
        return;
    else

        func(n - 1);

    cout << n << endl;

}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lhdy.png)

Comment: Always post code here. Never post images of code.

Comment: I've edited your code because your indentation does not do what I think you think it does.  Does the code make more sense to you now?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you call a function, you are pushing its stack frame onto the `call stack`. The stack frame consists of the function parameters, its local variables, and its return address. When you initially call `func()`, you pass in a value of 10, and then inside `func()`, you call `func()` again with 9. You continue calling `func()` with n-1 until you reach 0, at which point you return. Your call stack will look something like

```
frame containing 1
frame containing 2
...
frame containing 10
```

The stack will then "unwind", starting at the top and working down. Each function in the stack will begin where it left off, which is `cout`, and so each value will be printed out as the stack unwinds.

I'd recommend reading up on the call stack to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'll walk you through it.  We've all struggled with programming in the beginning so I don't mind helping.

func(10) is called

10 is greater than 0

func(9) is called

9 is greater than 0

etc...

func(1) is called

1 is greater than 0

func(0) is called

0 ==0

return

After the function returns, it calls every cout statement on the way back up to 10, because the function couldn't call it until all the func calls had eventually returned or reached the end of the function

So on the way out, it outputs 1,2,3,4....10

Answer (score -1):

So basically the recursive function keeps calling itself until it returns the value. So if you did func(2) it checks that 2 <= 0 then calls func(2-1) not printing until this new call completes. Then it checks if 2-1 <= 0, calls func(1-1), still not printing till the new function finishes. Now it sees that 1-1 is <= 0 so it returns 0. Now the previous function call can continue and it prints 2-1 = 1. Then the previous previous function can continue and it prints 2. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Does this not provide some explanation of the question? If you’re gonna downvote it that’s fine but if there is a flaw in my understanding I’d like to be aware of it.